# Use line numbers in text with EBGaramond-math and LuaTex

Tags: luatex, ebgaramond

I try to use `line numbers` in text with `EBGaramond-math` font and Luatex. With the code below, the numbers in math mode are lining, but in the text `oldstyle` font is used.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[EBGaramond12]{Numbers={Lining}} 
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\begin{document}
123

$123$
\end{document}
```

If I comment `\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}` the text numbers are lining.

After looking to the log file it seems that `ebgaramond-math` brings its own setting to `\defaultfontfeatures`, as written below numbers is configured twice.

> . Font family 'EBGaramond12(4)' created for font 'EBGaramond12' with options
>   . [Ligatures = TeX,Scale = 1,SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic},Extension =
>   . .otf,Numbers={Lining},Numbers = {Monospaced,OldStyle},UprightFont =
>   . *-Regular,ItalicFont = *-Italic,BoldFont = *-Regular,BoldItalicFont =
>   . *-Italic].

With the commented `ebgaramond-maths` the log file reads as follow.

> . Font family 'EBGaramond(0)' created for font 'EB Garamond' with options
>   . [Ligatures=TeX].

The same behaviour occurs if I use `XeLatex`. With `pdflatex` and `\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}` the `line numbers` are used in text with `ebgaramond-math`. What options do I need to use to use `line numbers` in text and math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ebgaramond-maths` package loads `ebgaramond`, which by default uses oldstyle numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[Numbers=Lining]

\begin{document}

123

$123$

\end{document}
```

[image]